# How to subset proof

Tags: induction

I don't understand how to prove subsets of a universe by induction.
I have only just started learning sets.

```
 Let B, C be subsets of a universe U.

 Prove that C' - B' = B - C
```

Thank you, any examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your notation is difficult to follow.  Perhaps stating in words what `B',C'` are (sets with particular contents) and what the set operation `-` is.  It may be that once you state the meaning, the proof will become evident.  If not then I can certainly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note
\begin{align*}
x\in C'-B'&\iff x\in C'\cap x\not\in B'\\
&\iff x\not\in C\cap x\in B\\
&\iff x\in B-C.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you I understand the logic from your example.

Comment: @Layken Good. Note however what I've written is a proof, not an example.